# Java: Could not find IntRange in Apache Commons Lang 3.3.2

Tags: java, apache, range

I would like to use the Range classes such as IntRange.  According to [this link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/Range.html), they should be found in

```
org.apache.commons.lang.math.Range
```

I downloaded Apache Commons Lang 3.3.2 from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi).  Unfortunately, its

```
org.apache.commons
```

does not have lang.  It has math3 but that does not appear to have any range classes.

Comment: You're using the 3.3.2 API with the 2.6 documentation. Here's the documentation root for the API you have downloaded: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/ specifically has the following package `org.apache.commons.lang3.Range<T>`

Comment: It looks like `IntRange` is not part of v3, and with that goes the ability to easily generate a range of ints as an array using [IntRange.toArray()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html#toArray())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.lang` is the package used for Apache Commons Lang 1 and 2.

For version 3, you need to use `org.apache.commons.lang3`.

In addition, the `Range` type has been moved to `org.apache.commons.lang3.Range`.

Comment: I'm migrating a code to use `org.apache.commons.lang3` instead of `org.apache.commons.lang`, what I am supposed to use instead of `DoubleRange`, `FloatRange`, `IntRange`, `LongRange`?

Comment: @AaA That's too complex to explain in a comment. Please ask a new question.

Comment: @AaA you can use org.apache.commons.lang3.Range instead of DoubleRange,FloatRange, ...